# returning rails object by id & routing problem?(Ruby rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, json, activerecord

This should have been a relatively simple one but I must be making a mistake with my routes or something. I want to return an active record as json based on an id. So heres what I have and in my eyes it should have worked.

The route:

```
match '/repository/infoid/(.:id)(.:format)' =>'repo#infoID', :via =>:get
```

The def within the controller

```
 def infoID
     puts (params[:id])
    @specificObject = myObject.find_by_id(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.xml{
        render :xml =>
        {
           :returnedObject => @specificObject
        }
      }
    end
  end
```

Why is it that when I go to my address of http://127.0.0.1:3008/repository/infoid/1.xml

I get no route found for /infoid/1.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
get '/repository/infoid/:id' => 'repo#infoID'
```

little refacrtoring for controller

```
def infoID
  @specificObject = MyObject.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html{}
    format.xml{
      render :xml => @specificObject
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: That looks nicer. Whats the difference between that and using via get?

Comment: no difference, just cleaner. also you have got unnecessary dot before `:id`

Comment: What about adding (.:format) at the end of the route. I want to be able to specify which format to return in. I will be serving json aswell as xml and just need to know how to direct them in the route

Comment: yo can add (.:format) as well, also you can specify `:as` option to create named path for your route